# How can I configure gradle build cache to normalize line endings for files?

Tags: spring, kotlin, gradle, gradle-cache

I have configured gradle build cache for my gradle project; however I'm seeing cache misses because of some specific files between linux (ci, wsl) and windows.

Here's an example of a file that works fine, and one that doesn't:

Windows line endings on Windows

```
src/main/kotlin/com/example/myservice/Application.kt / 2cb571d81042a8f959e144defd9f18b8
src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml / 7e3ed1680c889bf1cc5450a0c6e8620f
```

Unix line endings on Linux

```
src/main/kotlin/com/example/myservice/Application.kt / 2cb571d81042a8f959e144defd9f18b8
src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml / 09219d6006f7c1bc7de29d36fb706fad
```

Note that gradle computes the same hash on Windows and Linux for `Application.kt`, but a different hash for a resource file like `logback-spring.xml`.

In this example, it means that my gradle task `compileTestKotlin` misses the cache on windows, and has to re-compile. On linux, I get a cache hit, and the build does not have to re-compile.

The only differences between these files in both cases are line endings. If I pull `logback-spring.xml` on Windows, call `dos2unix` on `logback-spring.xml` to convert line endings to unix, and rerun the build, I get the correct hash for `logback-spring.xml` and I get a cache hit for the task.

So, gradle seems to be normalizing line endings correctly for `Application.kt`, but not for `logback-spring.xml`.

How can I fix this?